# Backing up MySQL in WampServer

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

How can I backup my 10MB MySQL database? I don't think WampServer supports mysqldump. I want to migrate it to a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/55429/how-to-backup-wamp-server) was asked on Server Fault